# Unable to get property 'getRandomValues' of undefined or null reference

Tags: botframework, skypedeveloper

I'm facing issue with Skype Web Control's sdk.min.js because of which bot doesn't work on IE.

Code:

```html
<span class="skype-button bubble " data-bot-id="vdasdsadsadyapzK5k-C7Zw9acGTpVddH9CCj8" data-color="#1C57D9"></span>
<span class="skype-chat" data-color-message="#27D1F0"></span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

The code works fine in Google Chrome, but not on IE. 
Error captured in console: Unable to get property 'getRandomValues' of undefined or null reference

[Here](https://github.com/capriza/node-busmq/issues/42) is similar fix reported but then we can not change sdk.min.js

Comment: If you look at the minified js you mentioned and the issue you mentioned, the "potential fix" is already in the minified js so it may not be the solution

Comment: That's unfortunate. Is there any other recommendation to handle it?

Comment: Is the following polyfill visible in DOM Explorer? `<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/vendors/polyfills.min.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Yes, that issue is still open. It seems like an issue with IE11 only. Any idea why?

Comment: If it doesn't work on IE11 then it doesn't work on IE11. Not everything is guaranteed to work on all versions of all browsers. I'll pass this along to the SWC team but we shouldn't count on getting a reply. My advice is to just include a message saying the control isn't supported in that browser. Better yet, use Web Chat instead of Skype.

Comment: Thank you Kyle. I would like to hear from SWC team. It's sad to see the behavior but when businesses start to pay Microsoft for using Azure services they expect basic things to work, at least in their browser, IE11 being latest on most Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've been informed by the SWC team that Microsoft is aware of the issue and is investigating. This could take a long time.